# SVG linearGradient coordinates calculation

Tags: svg

How can I calculate coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) values for linearGradient SVG element with different angles?. Need to achieve rotation of gradient.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks
SHAN

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gradientTransform="rotate(angle [cx cy])"` or you can calculate the angle you want and tweak the gradient vector (x1,y1)->(x2,y2).